# why character "." lost when using pandas to_csv

Tags: python, pandas

When I write values which end with"." to csv file. The "." character will be drop automatically. How can I keep the "."?

code:

```
S1 = s1 = Series([u'test1',u'8813.'])
S1.to_csv("test1.csv",index=None)
```

content in test1.csv file, "." in "8813." is lost:
test1
8813

Comment: Please post pandas and numpy version, this works fine in pandas `0.17.0` and numpy 1.9.2

Comment: here is the version: pandas 0.17.0rc1 and numpy 1.9.2

Comment: What's your python version?

Comment: No problem with pandas 0.15.3 and numpy 1.9.2 .

Comment: I run the code in ipython notebook:  ipython (4.0.0) , notebook (4.0.5). Python version is 2.7.10

Comment: I find it maybe the problem of read_csv ? when i use code :  " s2 = pd.read_csv("test1.csv") " .  s2.ix[0] is '8813'  dot is missing. but  when i use code "s2 = pd.read_csv("test1.csv",header = None) "  s2.ix[1] is '8813.' dot is kept

Comment: Actually I think this is just a display issue, if you do `s2.iloc[0][0]` you will see that it has kept the decimal point

Comment: Thanks All B.m And EdChun. I think EdChun is right. It's the display issue.